# Error Handling in TcpClient Socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I am new to Sockets this is my Code to send and receive data from a server.

This Code Works fine as long as the Client is able to receive data from the server.

In Case the Server does not sends the answer back in the given time then the application needs to send "No Answer Received".

How can i know if the recvBuffer is empty or NULL.

Currently the if Condition for the recvBuffer does not work and the application tries to send empty buffer which results in  "System.IndexOutOfRangeException error".

```
 class GetSocket
 {     
    public string SocketSendReceive(string server, int port, string cmd)
    {
        byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[1024];
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        tcpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 200;

         try
            {
                tcpClient.Connect(server, 6100);

            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

            }

            if (tcpClient != null && tcpClient.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    tcpClient.Client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cmd));
                    tcpClient.Client.Receive(recvBuffer);

                }

                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ErrorCode.ToString());
                }

                tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
                tcpClient.Client.Close();
                tcpClient.Client.Dispose();
                tcpClient = null;
                string tmp = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recvBuffer, 0, recvBuffer.Length);

                if (recvBuffer != null && recvBuffer.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] words = tmp.Split(null);
                    return words[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    return ("No Answer Received");
                }
            }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Stop looking at the receive buffer (which will _always_ be non-null and 1024 bytes in length, since you never do anything to change it), and refactor your code so all the decoding stuff goes in the `try` block after the `Receive()` call, while the `return ("No Answer...")` part goes in the `catch` block. The `SocketException` that gets thrown is what tells you the timeout occurred. For more info, see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the kind help, The Code works fine after i made changes suggested by you.

Comment: If you have solved the problem yourself, please post an answer describing what the problem was and how you fixed it, and then mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Following code works fine after making changes as suggested.

```
class GetSocket
{     
    public string SocketSendReceive(string server, int port, string cmd)
    {
        byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[1024];
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        tcpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 200;
        string tmp;


            try
            {
                tcpClient.Connect(server, 6100);

            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

            }



            if (tcpClient != null && tcpClient.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    tcpClient.Client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cmd));
                    tcpClient.Client.Receive(recvBuffer);
                    tmp = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recvBuffer, 0, recvBuffer.Length);
                    string[] words = tmp.Split(null);
                    return words[1];

                }

                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    return ("No Answer Received");
                }

            }
        return null;
    }


}
```